# Getting properly paths in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have custom `files` in directory `custom` inside `App`. One file is called update.php, so path is

```
App\custom\update.php
```

In update.php I have

```
$config = include __DIR__ . '/../../app/config/database.php';

$servername = $config['connections']['mysql']['host'];
$username   = $config['connections']['mysql']['username'];
$password   = $config['connections']['mysql']['password'];
$dbname     = $config['connections']['mysql']['database'];
```

Which reads database credentials. This works perfectly on Laravel 4.2 but doesn't work in Laravel 5.4

For Laravel 5.4 I've changed the path to

```
$config = include __DIR__ . '/../../../config/database.php';
```

But the error shows this `../../../` instead to execute it

```
include(/var/www/html/site/app/custom/../../../config/database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

How can I proper give the path?

Update: current code `database.php`

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'test',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '123321',
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

in update.php

```
$config = config_path('database.php');

$servername = config('database.connections.mysql.host');
$username = config('database.connections.mysql.host');
$password = config('database.connections.mysql.host');
$dbname = config('database.connections.mysql.host');


$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to include the file, rather use the helper method [`config()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-config)

```
$servername = config('database.connections.mysql.host');
```

Comment: Thanks, with this the error is `mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` on this `$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);`

Comment: Check your db credentials

Comment: I've updated question with current code. I'm 100% sure the credentials are correct. But why is using user localhost instead of root?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to include it, you could use `config_path()`:

```
$path = config_path('database.php');
```

Comment: Thanks, but then when I do bellow `$conn = new mysqli($config);` I've got `mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`